# How can one configure MS Teams so that guests can bypass the lobby by default for all my meetings?

Tags: microsoft-teams

My firm uses [Microsoft Teams](https://teams.microsoft.com). By default, when a **guest** — a Teams user from outside my organization — tries to join my meeting, they are first placed in the lobby and I must approve them before they can participate in the meeting.

As the organizer, I can change that setting for a given meeting, as shown in the screenshots below, but I don't want to have to manually change that setting for each new meeting.

How can I configure Teams such that when I create a new meeting the default setting for **Who can bypass the lobby** is **People in my org and guests**?

---

**Default meeting options:** *(Web App)*
[image]

**What I want the default to be:**
[image: Meeting Options screenshot: Who can bypass the lobby? (dropdown) People in my org; People dialing in can bypass the lobby (switch)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two settings involved here that affect whether a particular type of meeting participant bypasses the lobby:

1. Organizer's Default Lobby Policy
2. Organizer's Per-Meeting Setting

### Organizer's Default Lobby Policy

Set by your organization's IT department using the lobby settings in the Teams admin center.

### Organizer's Per-Meeting Setting

Set by the meeting organizer. Is one-off and meeting-specific.

### The Good News

While your IT department may have used a consistent lobby policy across many Teams users, they are designed as per-organizer policies. This means that your IT department, were it so inclined, could customize your organizer policy to match your preferences.

### The Bad News

If the IT department is not inclined to accommodate you, you are left only with the option to continue changing the settings on a one-off per-meeting basis, and thanking your stars the default policy settings allow that option, and they didn't disable it.

### Resources

- [Manage meeting and event policies in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/meeting-policies-overview)
- [IT Admins - Control who can bypass the meeting lobby in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/who-can-bypass-meeting-lobby)